# Which force act at pivot and How the maximum value of the normal component of the force at the pivot is 850 N?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

A horizontal bar has mass 5 kg, length 0.30 m
and has a mass M at one end as shown in
the accompanying schematic sketch. A cable
is attached at point A, 0.05 m from the pivot
point (fulcrum) P and its other end makes a
negligible angle with the a rod joined to the
pivot P. The top end of the rod is fixed to
the roof. The maximum tension the cable can
withstand is 1050 N. 
Then which force act at pivot and
How is:
The maximum value of the normal component of the force at the pivot is 850 N and 
what will be the the maximum value of the horizontal component of the force at the pivot?

First i have calculated the maximum mass of object M which came out to be 15 kg. Taking Tcos∅= T.( ∅ is the angle between rod and cable).
But i don't know the angle cable is making and am confused how to proceed solving this question. 
I don't have a clear idea how which acting will have components at pivot?
If Tcos∅ = T then normal component will also be equal to 1050 N but in answer it says its not.
Confused what will be the normal component of force at pivot??

[image]

Comment: This looks like a homework question, so just a hint about the angle you don't know.  The question says the angle between the cable and the rod is "negligible".

Comment: Yes thats why I took Tcos∅= T and normal component is also equal to Tcos∅ right? Then Normal component of force must also be equal to 1050N. But answers says its 850N don't know how

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assume a force upwards/downwards(as its a rod) from the pivot and equate upwards forces to downward forces. You should get the pivot force with sign convention.